# To create a view using 5 tables with all columns of all tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view, left-join

I have to create a view that joins together all of the columns in the CUSTOMERS, ORDERS, ORDERDETAILS, EMPLOYEES, PAYMENTS and PRODUCTS tables.
the schema for the table is below

[image: schema for above tables]

I tried the following query, though I am at a loss how to solve the above question :

```
create view     orders_view AS 
    select          *
    from            sys.customers c            
    left JOIN        EMPLOYEES e 
    on              c.SALESREPEMPLOYEENUMBER = e.EMPLOYEENUMBER    
    left join       sys.orders o     
    on              c.CUSTOMER NUMBER = o.CUSTOMERNUMBER
    left join       sys.orderdetails od
    on              o.ORDERNUMBER = od.ORDERNUMBER
    left join       sys.products p
    on              od.PRODUCTCODE = p.PRODUCTCODE
    left join       sys.PAYMENTS py
    on              c.CUSTOMERNUMBER = py.customernumber
```

I am a newbie with SQL and databases, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: what is the issue with the query??

Comment: Why the curly braces?

Comment: DO NOT create your tables in the SYS schema! This is an invitation to disaster.

Comment: Also - use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` rather than `CREATE VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks *alright*, but I don't think it will let you create a view if more than one column has the *same name*.

Since there are *duplicates*, e.g. `CITY`, I think the only way around it is to name all the columns and give unique names for duplicate columns.

Comment: @dmitry bychenko :  you are right about the duplicate column error. though can you suggest how i may change the above  query to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations on things going wrong:

1. You have curly braces that are not necessary (perhaps this is a typo in the question).
2. You are selecting `*`, but have duplicate column names (such as `productcode`), which prevents the view from being created.  Best practice:  list all the columns explicitly in the view.
3. You have `c.CUSTOMER NUMBER = o.CUSTOMERNUMBER`.  The space is probably a typo.  If not, change the name so the space is not part of the name.  Best practice:  Use identifiers that do not have to be escaped.
4. I am not aware of a `sys.customers` table.  The `sys` schema should only be used for internal Oracle objects.  ([Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSYS/systemtables.htm#TTSYS346) is one source.)

Comment: "duplicate column names" is an ERROR for view definitions; so avoiding them in this case is not only a best practice, it is required.

Comment: @gordon : 1 is a typo 2. so i need all the columns in all tables can you suggest how i may do it. 3. is a typo too 4. my practise tables got loaded in the  SYS schema

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the inputs. they helped me a lot in figuring out the answer. 
Following is the query for the question asked above.it gave me a view with columns from all tables.

```
create or replace  view     overall AS 
select                      c.*,
                            e.LASTNAME,
                            e.FIRSTNAME,
                            e.EXTENSION,
                            e.EMAIL,
                            e.OFFICECODE,
                            e.REPORTSTO,
                            e.JOBTITLE,
                            o.ORDERNUMBER,
                            o.ORDERDATE,
                            o.REQUIREDDATE,
                            o.SHIPPEDDATE,
                            o.STATUS,
                            o.COMMENTS,
                            od.PRODUCTCODE,
                            od.QUANTITYORDERED,
                            od.PRICEEACH,
                            od.ORDERLINENUMBER,
                            p.PRODUCTNAME,
                            p.PRODUCTLINE,
                            p.PRODUCTSCALE,
                            p.PRODUCTVENDOR,
                            p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,
                            p.QUANTITYINSTOCK,
                            p.BUYPRICE,
                            p.MSRP,
                            py.CHECKNUMBER,
                            py.PAYMENTDATE,
                            py.AMOUNT
from                        sys.customers c            
left JOIN                   EMPLOYEES e 
on                          c.SALESREPEMPLOYEENUMBER = e.EMPLOYEENUMBER  
left join                   sys.orders o     
on                          c.CUSTOMERNUMBER = o.CUSTOMERNUMBER
left join                   sys.orderdetails od
on                          o.ORDERNUMBER = od.ORDERNUMBER
left join                   sys.products p
on                          od.PRODUCTCODE = p.PRODUCTCODE
left join                   sys.PAYMENTS py
on                          c.CUSTOMERNUMBER = py.customernumber
;
```